# why log4j.zip is not in the build path after i use mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jar, zip, maven-3

i have the following lines in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
    <classifier>sources</classifier>
</dependency>
```

then i run

```
mvn dependency:resolve
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

but **i cannot find log4j.zip in .classpath, why?**

only that source.jar is in .classpath ...

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16-sources.jar"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a zip file it is considered as a resource file and not as a compile time dependency. Is should be there in the runtime and test classpaths.

Comment: but it is a library, what's more this log4j.zip is not in resource dir，why?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you remove the type, letting maven handle this gracefully ?

(FYI, In my projects, log4j comes as a transitive dep of slf4j, with packaging bundle)

Comment: maybe log4j.version.jar is not in maven's repo, only jar lib is available